Print not adhering to "Creality PEI Steel Plate for 3D Printer Ender 3 S1"
So I have an Ender 3 S1, and I recently bought a "Creality PEI Steel Plate for 3D Printer Ender 3 S1" to take models off easier of the build plate. But now whenever I try to print something, the filament doesn't adhere to the build plate. I regularly wash the plate and I always make sure its level before starting a print. Any clue as to what is going wrong?

You probably need to get the nozzle closer to the bed by decreasing the paper thickness distance. In Cura you can add a plugin (Z offset) to enable an option to lower the nozzle, please try that first.
